# Rerun Error Message While Creating a Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, return, pi

i am fairly new to SQL programming, and I am currently learning to create FUNCTIONS.

The problem that I am having, is creating the following FUNCTION.

```
create function CreatePI
(

)
returns decimal(10,6)
with returns null on null input
as
begin
declare @P as decimal(10,6)
set @P = 4*(1-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)+(1/9)-(1/11)+(1/13)-(1/15)
return @P
end
go
```

The above function is supposed to replicate the number PI. But the problem that I am having is:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CreatePI, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'return'.

If anyone could help me out with why I am getting this problem, it would be greatly appriciatead.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a closing paren on the `set` line:

```
set @P = 4*(1-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)+(1/9)-(1/11)+(1/13)-(1/15))
----------------------------------------------------------^
```